# Extracting mesh form a mask or face set

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am in dental technology and believe I can use Blender to fabricate better dentures. My first task is to form a baseplate over the dense mesh of a dental model. I have found the "Extract mesh from face set/mask" menu items but cannot figure out how to separate the resulting meshes and reposition them on the model to form the base of the denture.
[image]

This is a baseplate from META "Dental. As you can see it could be a mesh generated from the model surface and then add subsurface modifiers to give it the quality necessary.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hello :). Please add some illustrations/sketches describing what exactly you want to achieve. Not everyone knows what a "denture base plate" is. You can also share the file https://pasteall.org/blend/